# Not able to calculate the performance metrics in webdriverio devtools

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io, lighthouse, webdriver-io-v4

We are using WebdriverIO for calculating a performance metrics for our portal, but while calling browser.getMetrics() throwing following error:

```
LHError: NO_TTI_CPU_IDLE_PERIOD
at Function.findOverlappingQuietPeriods (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\computed\metrics\interactive.js:136:11)
at Function.computeObservedMetric (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\computed\metrics\interactive.js:165:41)
at Function.compute_ (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\computed\metrics\metric.js:65:21)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at Browser.runCommandWithHooks (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules@wdio\sync\build\wrapCommand.js:65:24)
at Browser.getMetrics (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules@wdio\sync\build\wrapCommand.js:44:44)
at Browser.next [as getMetrics] (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\monad.js:95:33)
at module.exports (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\utils\index.js:15:56)
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\tests\specs\qualified-req-contact.test.js:31:9)
at Context.executeSync (C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules@wdio\sync\build\index.js:25:22)
at C:\Users\sdas\OneDrive - ALLEGIS GROUP\Desktop\connected-tlp\allegis-automation-tlp-sfjs\node_modules@wdio\sync\build\index.js:46:68
```

We have tried many options but this error is coming all the time. Please suggest a pointer to resolve this issue.